Conditions for integrand recovering
Let $R(x, t) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$ be a closed subset for each fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in [0, \infty)$. Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left( - \iint_{R(x, t)} g(x', t') \, dx' \, dt' \right) dt,
$$
where $g: \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ is a smooth (e.g., $C^\infty$) function.
Question: Under what conditions on the function $g$ and the regions $R(x, t)$ is it possible to uniquely recover $g$ from the function $f$? Specifically, can $g$ be expressed in terms of $f$ if, for example, the mapping $f$ is injective? Essentially, I want to infer some analytical information on $g$, given $f$.
Some thoughts: I want to infer properties of $g$, as a function of $f$ and $R$. Let's see two simpler examples.

In the case $g(x,t)\equiv g$ is constant, and $R(x,t)$ is the cone region given between $(x-t',0)$, $(x+t',0)$, and $(x,t)$, we get
$$
\iint_{R(x,t)} g(x,t)\,dx' dt'=g\int_0^t \int_{x-t'}^{x+t'} \,dx'dt'=g t^2
$$
and thus
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-gt^2} \,dt=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{g}}
$$
which I can easily invert. I am interested in studying properties of $g$ if $R$ is a bit more general.

Another interesting case could be a time-homogeneous $g$, i.e., $g(x,t)=g(x)$. Take $R(x,t)$ to be the cone region as before. Then, swapping the order of integration, we get
$$
\int_0^t \int_{x-t'}^{x+t'} g(x') \,dx'dt'=\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\int_{|x'-x|}^t g(x')\,dt'dx'=\int_{x-t}^{x+t} (t-|x'-x|)g(x')\,dx'
$$
so we get
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\int_{x-t}^{x+t} (t-|x'-x|)g(x')\,dx'\right)\,dt.
$$
Can we invert and write $g(x)$ as a function of $f(x)$ in this case? Could the D'Alembert operator help?



It seems unlikely you'll be able to recover $g$ exactly from $f$ except for very constrained $R(x,t)$. One complication is if $R(x,t)$ has symmetries. For instance $R(x,t) = [-e^{-t}, e^{t}] \cup [0,1]$ is symmetric via flipping the sign of the first coordinate, and we'd have $$ \iint_{R(x,t)} g(x',t')dx',dt' = \iint_{R(x,t)} g(-x',t') dx',dt' $$ Thus the mapping $g\mapsto f$ is not injective.

Also, does't look like the map $\phi \mapsto \int_0^\infty \exp[-\phi(\cdot, t)] dt$ is injective regardless of the choice of $R(x,t)$.

@TrevorNorton I basically want to look for properties of $g$ depending on the assumption on $R$. What tools do I need? I have added a simple example (please see the edit).

Perhaps looking into integral transforms may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform I'm not too familiar with these techniques, but I think you'll need to narrow the scope of your question to get useful answers. What can we assume about $R$? What properties of $g$ are we interested in? Can $g$ be any smooth function? I think in the most general case, you'll likely not be able to say anything definite and useful about $g$ given $f$.

This is definitely the way to go. $R$ will definitely have a special form. I will revisit this soon. Thank you!

Your biggest issue here is that $g$ is a function of two dimensions while $f$ is a function of only one dimension. While it is possible to completely encode two dimensions into one, it not possible to do so smoothly. So this reduction of dimension is going to include a reduction of information, which cannot be recovered in general. Your example works because the $g$ in it is actually $0$-dimensional pretending to be $2$-dimensional.

@PaulSinclair Yes, that is true. What if $g(x)$ in only space dependent? I am wondering if the D'Alembert operator or something similar could help. I have edited the question to add this case. In general, I am trying to infer what conditions I need on $g$ and $R$ to be able to invert the problem (no information loss), and write $g$ in terms of $f$, or find some type of bounds (or distribution) for $g$. Where can I learn more about this type of problem? This must relate to Minkowski spaces.

Here is a follow-up relative to a particular case.
